How can I access the managed configuration provided by an MDM system in a iOS app Action Extension?
I have a question regarding reading the configuration of a managed app deployed via an MDM system. The application has an Action Extension and can receive shared files via this extension.
The problem I am facing is that I can read the managed configuration in the host app by accessing the UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "com.apple.configuration.managed") dictionary. With this, I can configure the host app. However, I am unable to read this configuration key in the Action Extension part of the application.
My question is whether there is any possibility to read the managed configuration even in the extension. So far, I have been unable to figure out how to read it.
I found the sample code, but it was not very helpful since it is very basic and does not deal with extensions at all.
I have tried accessing the configuration with the same code as in the host app using the standard user defaults UserDefaults.standard. I have also tried accessing it from a custom instance of user defaults created with the host app bundle ID UserDefaults(suiteName: "bundleID").
None of these instances had the key com.apple.configuration.managed in them.
Any hints are appreciated.

An extension cannot access those settings directly because they are placed in the sandbox file system of the app,  not the extension. Your app could copy the value to a shared user defaults and then your extension can access it from there.
